# How to parse text for events (i.e. meet me at 8pm tonight)?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, parsing, mobile

This was a difficult question to phrase since we think of events as in callbacks, however I'm actually speaking about engagements with a time and place. I have built an app for a client and one of the features is to parse messages for event syntax. We've thought about introducing a special syntax for the user to follow, but I think an open approach would be more practical.

So for example:

user1 sends a message to user2: "hey do you want to meet up at the bar @ 8pm tonight?"

I want to be able to parse that string for key phrases (tonight,tomorrow,etc) and times (#am/pm).

Is there a best practice for this? A good example would be the way Apple does it inside iMessage.

Comment: You seem to be after **Natural language processing**. More about it at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Answer (score 1):

Seems what you should more or less do some research on is called a Natural Language Processor. Wikipedia defines it as : a field of computer science, artificial intelligence, and linguistics concerned with the interactions between computers and human (natural) languages [source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing ].

A reputable library for .Net to do things like this is sharpnlp.. at http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps.